# Метод для упоминания участника в чате pyrogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, pyrogram

Есть ли метод для упоминания кого-то в чате на pyrogram? Очень нужно для скрипта

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого есть [mention](http://docs.pyrogram.org/topics/text-formatting#basic-styles)

```
app.send_message(
  "me",
  "[mention](tg://user?id=12345)",
  parse_mode="markdown"
)
```

Comment: А если текст занимает несколько строк?